# RoboMongo gte date query

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

Why would RoboMongo 1.0 return the following Object:

```
{
"code" : "bar",
"value" : 133.63,
"at" : "2017-05-03T10:42:08.000+1000"
"_id" : ObjectId("590927605105bf499025c202")
}
```

from the following query:

```
db.getCollection('foo').find({ "at" : 
 { $gte : new ISODate("2017-05-03T10:45:00.000+1000")}
})
```

?

I'm trying to get all the records *after* 10:45 am

Comment: is `at` stored as `date`? or is it just a `string`?

Comment: as a Timestamp `"at" : Timestamp(1493772128, 10),`

Answer (score 0):

You can query using robo3t client like:

```
db.getCollection('foo').find({"at": {$gte: new ISODate("2020-04-26")}}).sort({"_id":-1})
```

`sort({"_id":-1})` is used to sort in descending order to get the latest item inserted.

Answer (score -1):

**[Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library** helps to change the Date and make which ever Date you want

you can require **npm module** by:-

```
var moment = require('moment');
var fromDate = moment().set('hour', 10).set('minute', 45).set('second', 0).set('millisecond', 0).toDate();
```

if want to set perticular UTC date you can simply put in `moment("DateYouWant")` .

query will be  :-

```
db.getCollection('foo').find({ "at" : 
 { $gte : fromDate }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: What's with the assumption that the code that populates the Collection is NodeJS?  Besides, I already said the datum is a `Timestamp`